# How to update using select query from the same table with correct id?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple task (they said!), which I need to update the table column using a `select` statement.

Something like below:

[image: Test table]

So let's say this table A, I have a bad data on previous `pcsProduces` column,
right now I want to multiply the cavities and `heatcyclecount` and then I would like to update the `pcsProduces` column to a proper value.

The problem is, I have thousands of record, which I really appreciate if someone can help me by showing how to use simple update and select query.

Comment: if you want to simple update your pcsProduces column by multiply of (cavities * heatcyclecount), then just use update tablename set pcsProduces  = cavities * heatcyclecount.

Comment: Owh God, thank you, that's the easiest way!

Comment: I think it will be helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

Just fire SQL Update Command like :

```
 update tablename set pcsProduces = cavities * heatcyclecount
```

Answer (score 1):

You have at least 2 options:

1. Updating the whole table with an update statement (where clause is optional):

   ```sql
   update TbYourTable
   set pcsProduces = cavities * heatsOrCyclecount
   where pcsProduces != cavities * heatsOrCyclecount
   ```
2. Using a computed column (MS SQL Syntax)

   ```sql
   create table [TbYourTable]
   (
      [Id]                int       identity(1,1) not null
   ,  [domainS]           int                     not null
   ,  [tStations]         int                     not null
   ,  [itemNo]            int                     not null
   ,  [defaultCavities]   int                     not null
   ,  [missingCavities]   int                     not null
   ,  [cavities]          int                     not null
   ,  [heatsOrCyclecount] int                     not null
   ,  [shift]             nvarchar  (max)             null
   ,  [pcsProduces]       as ([cavities] * [heatsOrCyclecount]) persisted not null -- peristed clause is optional

   ,  constraint [PK_TbYourTable] primary key nonclustered
      (
         [Id] asc
      )

   ) on [primary];
   ```